# Read XML File in Xamarin

Tags: c#, android, xml, xamarin

I am new to Xamarin and am looking to read an XML File in a Portable Class library.

The file can either be embedded or online, I have done some research and found options for both, but everything I have found is overly complicated for such a simple task.  I am wondering if anyone has an easy, clean way to accomplish this.

The only stipulations are that you use the Portable Class Library so that the iOS, Android and Windows Phone projects can all use this same method.

Context:
Basically I am building a List of Items that will be placed into a ListViewer.  Each Item has a Name string and an ImageSource string.  I have xml documents that have the information I want to use, I just need an easy way to read these xml files inside Xamarin.

Thank you for any help provided!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is what I have.  I am using xml files that are stored online, downloading them into a Stream and then passing the Stream to the XMLReader class.  All of this is CrossPlatform code.

If you would like to embed the xml files as app resources as @Dimitris Batsougiannis explains in his comment, that is the second option.  But once you have your stream the code would be the same.  Simply, pass in your stream to the BuildItemList method.

```
public class ItemHelper
{
    public static bool IsReadingXML { get; set; }
    public static List<Item> ItemList { get; set; }

    public static void BeginReadXMLStream(string currFileName)
    {
        IsReadingXML = true;

        string ImagesRootFolder = "http://www.mywebsite.com/";
        HttpWebRequest httpRequest = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(ImagesRootFolder + currFileName);
        httpRequest.BeginGetResponse(new AsyncCallback(FinishWebRequest), httpRequest);
    }

    private static void FinishWebRequest(IAsyncResult result)
    {
        IsReadingXML = true;

        HttpWebResponse httpResponse = (result.AsyncState as HttpWebRequest).EndGetResponse(result) as HttpWebResponse;
        if (httpResponse.StatusCode == HttpStatusCode.OK)
        {
            Stream httpResponseStream = httpResponse.GetResponseStream();
            BuildItemList(httpResponseStream);
        }
    }

    public static void BuildItemList(Stream xmlStream)
    {
        string ImagesRootFolder = "http://www.mywebsite.com/";
        List<Item> returnValue = new List<Item>();

        try
        {
            using (XmlReader myXMLReader = XmlReader.Create((xmlStream)))
            {
                while (myXMLReader.Read())
                {
                    if (myXMLReader.Name == "photo")
                    {
                        double tempPrice = 0.0;
                        double.TryParse(myXMLReader.GetAttribute("price"), out tempPrice);

                        returnValue.Add(new Item(
                            myXMLReader.GetAttribute("info"),
                            tempPrice,
                            ImagesRootFolder + myXMLReader.GetAttribute("image"),
                            myXMLReader.GetAttribute("sku")
                            ));
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        catch { }

        //Done
        ItemList = returnValue;
        IsReadingXML = false;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

PCL's don't have access to System.IO.File, but do have access to System.IO.FileStream.

I believe one way to solve your problem is add your xml files in your PCL as resources, load the file in a `FileStream` object and read it with StreamReader, have a look at this article

http://developer.xamarin.com/guides/cross-platform/xamarin-forms/working-with/files/

Although I'd suggest you to convert your files to json, since I don't know if XML Deserializers are available in PCL.

With json you can use the json.net library and easily use your files.

Comment: Thank you for the link to the Embedded files article, I went with online files, you can see my answer below.  Cheers!

Comment: @MattyMerrix make sure to click the vote up / answer if my post helped you.